# @font-face Gotham not working on Chrome (Mac)

Tags: macos, google-chrome, fonts, font-face

I have included a font (via @font-face) called Gotham and it's working on PC (all browsers) and Mac (all browsers) except Chrome on Mac.

I have the following font files:

```
Gotham-Regular.eot
Gotham-Regular.woff
Gotham-Regular.otf
Gotham-Regular.svg
Gotham-Regular.ttf
```

And on the css, this declaration:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Gotham";
    src: url('fonts/Gotham-Regular.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Gotham-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/Gotham-Regular.svg#Gotham') format('svg'),
    url('fonts/Gotham-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/Gotham-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The thing is, I have another font installed this way and it's showing up (Antonio). Only this Gotham font doesn't.

Not sure what's the issue.

Comment: I don't think you're using "installed" correctly. If you just have these fonts in an asset folder/dir for your webpage to use via a CSS @font-face, they're not installed; they're just loose files. If you have them *actually* installed on your OS, then that will make testing them as webfont much, much harder. With that said, every normal browser now supports WOFF (including IE since v9) so you can probably get away with just using the one format.

Comment: Don't let Hoefler & Co. find out you're using Gotham without a webfont license. They're more aggressive than most font foundries.

Comment: Ok, I changed the term "installed". What I meant was I used @font-face to include this font and saved the font files in a folder.